# call setState() on a State object for a widget

Tags: flutter, dart

The code below flutter deals with the management of a bottombar when the code is executed, click on the `Icons.add` button and then change bottom element the system displays following error:

**Error:**

> [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _HomeViewScreenState#d0762(lifecycle state: defunct, tickers: tracking 1 ticker)

This error happens if you call `setState()` on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls `setState()` from a timer or an animation callback.

The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the `dispose()` callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling `setState()` to ensure the object is still in the tree.

This error might indicate a memory leak if `setState()` is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during `dispose()`.

[**Flutter Code**](https://pastebin.com/Birv1fkc)

[**Flutter Code HomeState**](https://pastebin.com/W3d8P5Vg)

Comment: Where is `_HomeViewScreenState` ?  unable to find in the provided code.

Comment: @dev-aentgs i had code

Comment: In `Widget bottomBar()` , `super.dispose()` is called in `addClick: () {  super.dispose(); },` on line no. 90 of the [Flutter Code HomeState](https://pastebin.com/W3d8P5Vg) code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check if the widget is mounted. Instead of calling `setState` directly, use:

```
if (mounted)
    setState(() {});
```

Explanation:
When you navigate away from the screen, widget gets disposed. So you cannot call `setState()` on it